# wasabeef's Blurry library not effecting on TextView

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, blurry

I am using wasabeef's Blurry library. I create ConstraintLayout and inside put images, button and TextView. All works except TextView. Actually it also works somehow, but not properly. It gives only smooth shadow around TextView. I used also andoird's BlurMaskFilter. It did not work when I used TextViews as children of parent view with forEach(). But with single TextView works fine. But still I want to solve problem with wasabeef's Blurry library.

Here is the result:

[image: The Result]

Answer (score 0):

How about adding one more view upper the whole profile and apply blur onto it?

Then you can get all blurry effect from the screen.

Comment: Tried, didn't help ( again TextView unreachabe, the same result